# Error during template rendering In template unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'map' and 'int'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using django version 1.11 and was trying to build up wine recommendation

code for wine_detail is

### {{ wine.name }}

{{ wine.review_set.count }} reviews ({{ wine.average_rating | floatformat }} average rating)

i got the error in line 2 .

Comment: Please add your view and models

Comment: It seems someone wrote the `average_rating` property to be `return map(something, all_ratings) / number_of_ratings`, rather than `sum(map(...)) / number_of_ratings`